# Выборы мэра предложения между запятой и пробелом. Чьи дебаты вам больше нравятся?

Tags: запятые, присоединительная-конструкция

`Предприятия, а также школы и государственные учреждения(,) используют глобальные сети для...`

Не понимаю, обособить присоединительную конструкцию или нет. Но Википедия не обособила. В смысле, дебаты пробела Википедии больше понравились.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Предприятия, **а также школы и государственные учреждения** используют глобальные сети для передачи данных сотрудникам, студентам, клиентам, покупателям и поставщикам из различных мест по всему миру.*

Здесь ***А ТАКЖЕ*** используется как соединительный союз, то есть нет обособления. А что он там делает? Он разделяет однородные члены **на две группы**.

2. Для обособления однородный член должен иметь **добавочное** значение, тогда союз ***ТАКЖЕ*** будет присоединительным, например:

**Однородный ряд:**   *Предприятия, **а также школы и государственные учреждения** используют глобальные сети для передачи данных.*

**Обособление.**  *Многие предприятия, **а также ряд школ и государственных учреждений**, используют глобальные сети для передачи данных.*

3. При выборе варианта можно ориентироваться как на **грамматику**, так и на **семантику** сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш голос. Больше голосов за пробел. Теперь решено, что мэром предложения будет пробел.

Comment: Максим, пробел чаще используется, он более популярен. Для обособления  нужны особые требования. Спасибо вам  за приемку ответа.

Comment: Если хорошое глагольное согласование происходит, то ставим запятушонку.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, мы такие конструкции не обособляем. Ещё пример: *Я, а также мой кот вместе пошли в лес.*

[https://popravilam.com/blog/131-soyuz-a-takzhe-mezhdu-odnorodnymi-chlenami.html#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%3A,%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20](https://popravilam.com/blog/131-soyuz-a-takzhe-mezhdu-odnorodnymi-chlenami.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%3A,%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20)

Comment: Скажите, а можно обособить оборот в таком предложении:  Я и мой приятель, а также мой кот, решили пойти на кухню, где много было вкусного всякого.

Comment: Я думаю, надо использовать или тире, или скобки, или только одну запятую.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но зачем нам такие сильные знаки, когда можно обойтись обособлением?  В вузовской  грамматике Кустовой союз А ТАКЖЕ может быть как соединительным, так и присоединительным. Но на практике мы видим преобладание соединительного союза. Кроме того, в большинстве случаев оборот с таким союзом  стоит или в конце предложения, или за ним следует другая конструкция, так что и не поймешь, присоединительный он или соединительный.